# Zuul Routing: Static Resources Not Found Issue

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

When Zuul routes a request to, say, login page, the static resources (css, js etc.) cannot be correctly located. A `404 Not Found` error will be returned.

I have the following routing setting first:

```
ui:
  path: /ui/**
  url: http://serviceHost:8082/ui/
```

And it's working well. So when I visit `http://zuulHost/ui/login/`, I'll get an `index.jsp` and then the browser will request the static resources, whose paths are like:

```
/ui/ext/ext-dev.js
```

The browser will use `http://zuulHost/ui/ext/ext-dev.js`, for e.g, for that resource. And Zuul will route it to `http://serviceHost:8082/ui/ext/ext-dev.js` according to its setting.

But then I want to forward the request to the root `/` path to the login page, and I added:

```
root:
  path: /
  url: http://serviceHost:8082/ui/login/
```

This time, after the browser gets the `index.jsp` file, it will request the resources using:

```
http://zuulHost/ext/ext-dev.js
```

So in this case, the context `/ui` is lost, because the browser doesn't know about it since I'm forwarding the request in zuul internally. The url in the browser is still `http://zuulHost`. And zuul won't know where to route `http://zuulHost/ext/ext-dev.js`, since there's not a match in its routing table.

I wonder if there's a solution to it. I think it's a quite common issue when doing forwarding in proxy servers. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you add a route ext to the url: `http://serviceHost:8082/ui/ext/`?

Comment: There is such  a route. The problem is that there's no route for `http://zuulHost/ext/`. The context `/ui` is lost.

Comment: did you try adding stripPrefix: false